# Method from extended class call another method from extended class

Tags: java, class, wear-os

I'd like to ask you for your great Java knowledge.

I have these classes:

```
public class WearableAdapter extends WearableListView.Adapter {

   public void RemoveOrder(){
     //some stuff
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

public void onSwipeRight() {
        System.out.println("SWIPE TO RIGHT");
        Wearable.this.RemoveOrder(); // <-- Does not work -->
    }
}
```

My question is how to call RemoveOrder() from onSwipeRight()? Or better how to do it properly?

I received error : ... `is not an enclosing class`, but new definition via

```
WearableAdapter wear = new WearableAdapter();
```

didn't help either.

What I am trying to achieve : based on user action (swipe, click ...) do some actions ove list and refresh screen via adapter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am new to Java . Usually I work with Python or Powershell. And this will code for our MVP prototype. Application will be used on Android wear 2.0

Comment: Is `OnSwipeTouchListener` an inner class of `Wearable`? Otherwise what you do won't work, or you'll need to provide the listener with an explicit reference to the right instance `Wearable`.

Comment: No it isn't inner class. Listener should be linked to what Wearable.xxx ? Can you guide me please?